# Switch between view controllers in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, navigation

Lets say I have 4 screens (iPhone view controllers) in my App, and I like to navigate between them.
For example:

```
> 1 ----> 2
> 2 ----> 3
> 3 ----> 2 (With new data)
> 2 ----> 4
> 4 ----> 1
```

This is off course just an example, what is the correct way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Udi I,

the correct way to achieve such type of navigation is through [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). From Apple documentation:

> The `UINavigationController` class implements a specialized view controller that manages the navigation of **hierarchical content**. This navigation interface makes it possible to present your data efficiently and also makes it easier for the user to navigate that content. This class is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and later.

The following APIs allow you to navigate in the stack

```
– pushViewController:animated:
– popViewControllerAnimated:
– popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
– popToViewController:animated:
```

If you need to pass data between controllers, just inject them like the following:

```
// within the third controller

UIViewController* secondController = // new controller
secondController.dataToInject = // ...
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];
```

where `dataToInject` could be defined in `SecondController` as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id dataToInject;
```

Hope that helps.

**P.S.** The code is written in objective-c but with small modifications is valid also for MonoTouch.
Use `this` instead of `self`, for example.